# Looking to write code for a google sheet that creates a new folder in a specific place on my google drive for each new response

Tags: google-apps-script

Basically, I'm looking to write code so that every time a new Google form response comes in, it takes the information from the second column (excluding the first row as they're headers), and uses that as the name for a folder that it makes in google drive (in a specific parent folder).

Hopefully that all makes sense!

I've used CHATGPT to help, as well as looking through multiple forumns but I just cant get it to work. It doesn't seem to do anything! Here's the code it provided me:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {`
  try {
    // Get the active sheet
    var sheet = e.range.getSheet();

    // Get the submitted values
    var values = e.values;

    // Get the heading from the second cell in the last row
    var heading = values[1]; // Assuming the second column (B) contains the heading

    // Specify the parent folder ID where you want to create the new folder
    var parentFolderId = "your_parent_folder_id"; // Replace with the actual folder ID

    // Create a new folder in the specified location
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
    var newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(heading);

    // Create a new spreadsheet
    var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(heading);

    // Move the new spreadsheet to the newly created folder
    DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).moveTo(newFolder);

    // Log the URL of the new spreadsheet in the current sheet (optional)
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).setValue(newSpreadsheet.getUrl());

  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error: " + error.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you [install the trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)?